# What is a good way to get this structure in a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to get this data structured in a JSON file, which seems most practical for later usage. But I'm struggling how to actually do this. Can you help with directions and maybe an example related to this case?

```
player_a:
    match_id:
            winner:
                name: player_x
                a: 2
                b: 120
                c:  30
                d: 2.1

            losers:
                name: player_q
                a: 1
                b: 112
                c:  40
                d: 1.1

                name: player_v
                a: 1
                b: 132
                c:  40
                d: 1.1

                name: player_r
                a: 1
                b: 112
                c:  40
                d: 1.1

                name: player_e
                a: 1
                b: 132
                c:  40
                d: 1.1

    match_id:
            winner:
                name: player_w
                a: 2
                b: 120
                c:  30
                d: 2.1

            losers:
                name: player_q
                a: 1
                b: 112
                c:  40
                d: 1.1
player_b:
    match_id: etc etc
    match_id: etc etc

player_c: etc
```

Later on I want to iterate over this file. That Im familiar with, but building the file like in the example, I don't know.

update:
Something like this is what I do understand, but with the example I have I don't know how to proceed.

```
import json

data = {}
data['people'] = []
data['people'].append({
'name': 'Scott',
'website': 'stackabuse.com',
'from': 'Nebraska'

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: What part is confusing? Just go through and start adding brackets to turn it into JSON format.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Do you have a python dictionary, a class, something else? Or do you just want to create the file manually?

Comment: I notice that you have repeated instances of `match_id`. Is `match_id` just a stand in for labels that will be different, or do you mean to use `match_id` in your actual JSON file?

Comment: @jjramsey match_id those will be unique strings, so not using the actual word.

Comment: @PaulRenauld That is also open. I get the data from several API calls to a public api. So Im not really tied to anyting yet. I dont have a dictionary yet, nor a class. Couple bits from seperate API calls and wanted to combine everything to look like this.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Not confusion as such, but not really clear to me what I should start with. The "correct" way to do this. Creating a simple, almost flat, JSON I understand.(Added that to orignal post now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do something like this:

```py
data = {}
data["player_a"] = {"match_id1": {}, "match_id2": {}}

data["player_a"]["match_id1"]["winner"] = {
    "name": "player_x",
    "a": 2, "b": 120, "c": 30,"d": 2.1
}

# Repeat for additional match ids and players ...
```

and then dump `data` to a JSON file as you've done before. You'd probably want to associate the `"losers"` key with a list of dictionaries, rather than a single dictionary as I did with the "winner" key.

Comment: Yes, this seems to perfectly work for me. The list of dictionaries for the "losers" I will try to do that as well. Thanks for your solution!